# Weird output on my node.js server - deleting object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've following output from node.js in terminal:

node server.js

```
{ hand: 
   [ [ [Object], [Object] ],
     [ [Object], [Object] ],
     [ [Object], [Object] ],
     [ [Object], [Object] ] ],
  deck: 
   [ { suit: 'c', rank: 'a' },
     { suit: 'd', rank: 'a' },
     { suit: 'h', rank: 'a' },
     { suit: 's', rank: 'a' },
     { suit: 'c', rank: 'k' },
     { suit: 'd', rank: 'k' },
     { suit: 'h', rank: 'k' },
     { suit: 's', rank: 'k' },
     { suit: 'c', rank: 'q' },
     { suit: 'd', rank: 'q' },
     { suit: 'h', rank: 'q' },
     { suit: 's', rank: 'q' },
     { suit: 'c', rank: 'j' },
     { suit: 'd', rank: 'j' },
     { suit: 'h', rank: 'j' },
     { suit: 's', rank: 'j' },
     { suit: 'c', rank: '10' },
     { suit: 'd', rank: '10' },
     { suit: 'h', rank: '10' },
     { suit: 's', rank: '10' },
     { suit: 'c', rank: '9' },
     { suit: 'd', rank: '9' },
     { suit: 'h', rank: '9' },
     { suit: 's', rank: '9' },
     { suit: 'c', rank: '8' },
     { suit: 'd', rank: '8' },
     { suit: 'h', rank: '8' },
     { suit: 's', rank: '8' },
     ,
     ,
     ,
     ,
     ,
     ,
     ,
      ] }
```

First of all, why cannot I see `Object` inside hand? I'm doing console.dir on this object.

Second, why do I've empty comma area? I simply do `delete deck[i]`

This could be more of a javascript question :)

js:

```
function deal(num_cards,num_players,deck) {
    var hand = [];
    var i = deck.length - 1;
    for (var p = num_players - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
        var player = [];
        for (var c = num_cards - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
            player.push(deck[i]);
            delete deck[i];
            i--;
        };
        hand[p] = player;
    };
    return {"hand":hand,"deck":deck};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question: your `deck[i]` does not have a `toString` method. Define one that would give you the information you want on it, and that will replace the `[object Object]` output you're getting. For example, if your array contains `Card` objects, you could do:

```
Card.prototype.toString = function() {
    return 'suit=' + this.suit + ';rank=' + this.rank;
}
```

For the second question: `delete` does **not** remove the element. It basically sets it to `undefined`. Try using `deck.splice(i, 1)` instead.

Comment: Cant I keep my deck[i] as object? I will be able to access it right? in the returned variable?

Comment: That is not the reason why it prints `[object Object]`. Why would it work for objects which are less nested ?

Answer (score 1):

1. `console.dir` uses `util.inspect` for which default depth is 2. To show it with proper nesting use  `util.inspect(obj,{depth:null});`
2. `delete` sets the value of an index to `undefined`. So you would still see the keys. Like DoorknobChatbot said `splice` would serve the purpose here.